# Show all machine's internal IP addresses (Windows XP)?

Tags: router, ip-address, intranet

I have 3 Windows XP machines connection in a small home network.
(2 of the 3 have no screen or keyboard.)

What's the easiest way for me to find out each of the machines internal IP addresses?

Is there a DOS command I can run from Machine #1... and ask it "show each machine's IP address"?

Answer (score 3):

If you have nmap you can do:
nmap -sP 192.168.1.1/24

where 192.168.1.1 is network adress and 24 is netmask

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Angry Ip Scanner](http://www.angryip.org/w/About) in the past.  It is able to scan ip addresses in any range.  It can also scan the ports for the ip addresses.  It doesn't require an installation.

Also, you could use [network Magic](http://purenetworks.com/download/).  It provides a free trial for 7 days.  It will show you all the computers/devices connected to your network in a GUI setup.

Answer (score 2):

No one else has mentioned this but many routers will have a page that lists devices that it gave a address to through DHCP. If all of your machines use DHCP, check the configuration page of your router.

Answer (score 1):

Free software:

SolarWinds has a free IP Address Tracker.

Download it at http://www.solarwinds.com/products/freetools/ip_address_tracker/

It will probe for IP addresses

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if Network (in Explorer) shows them, as it will try to use Windows file share discovery to show all the computers on the network. If not, the easiest thing might be to use a tool like nmap to do a fast ping scan of your network.

Comment: Where is "Network in Explorer"?

Comment: @Susan: Start button -> Network

Answer (score 0):

You ask for a command from a DOS prompt so I'll assume CMD. You can accomplish what you ask by pinging the broadcast address of a network then checking your arp cahce. This requires no additional software:

Simply ping your broadcast (on a class c address it's .255) so `ping 192.168.1.255 -t`. Let this run for a little bit 1-2 minutes should be fine. Then run `arp -a`, you should see all the address that are responding to ICMP requests on that subnet. It's basically the same thing angry IP scanner is doing...

Comment: @darr247 points out an issue with your answer, but also, the image next to your nick ot grossly offensive to many people - to many christians or to people that sympathise with their feelings.

Comment: @barlop that symbol is the punk rock band "Bad Religion"s [logo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_Religion#Logo) and has nothing to to do with christianity. In fact in a documentary the band talks about regretting their choice of logo due to people dismissing the band without even listening to them.

Comment: why not make your own logo for them like a picture of them. or that logo with a picture of a guitar. Or the words "Bad Religion(THE BAND)" or "The Band",  included in that logo. or "Bad Religion(STFW)"

Comment: Late comment, but I think you mean 192.168.1.255 is the broadcast, not 254.  .254 is a valid IP address on this subnet.

Answer (score -2):

1. open the run dialog (windows key + r)
2. type `cmd` and hit enter
3. type `ipconfig /all` and hit enter

also returns MAC addresses

Comment: How does this solve the problem? It tells you the IPs associated with _your_ machine; it does nothing to tell you about IPs for other machines on the network.

Comment: this was merely a suggestion for a script ( btw how does your or this comment contribute to her question and what the heck is an external ip address)

Comment: How does _your answer_ contribute to her question?